# Deconvolution with caffe

Tags: convolution, caffe

I was wondering if it is possible to perform a deconvolution of images in Caffe using a point spread function of objective at a given focal point. Something along the lines of [this approach](http://yuzhikov.com/articles/BlurredImagesRestoration1.htm).

If yes, what would be the best way to proceed?

Comment: There is this NIPS'04 paper doing something that: "Deep Convolutional Neural Network for Image Deconvolution" http://machinelearning.wustl.edu/mlpapers/paper_files/NIPS2014_5485.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to deconvolve images using Caffe (and CNN in general), but the approach may not be as general as you hope it to be.

CNNs can take blurry image as an input and output sharp image. As the networks are convolutional, the input can be of any size. This can be easily done in Caffe using Convolutional layers and Euclidean Loss layer. Optionally, you can experiment with adding some pooling and deconvolution layers.

CNNs can be trained to deconvolve images for specific blur PSF as in your link. (see: [[Xu et al.:Deep Convolutional Neural Network for Image Deconvolution. NIPS 2014]](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/5485-deep-convolutional-neural-network-for-image-deconvolution.pdf)). This works well but you have to re-train the CNN for each new PSF (which takes lot of time).

I've tried to train CNNs to do blind deconvolution (PSF is not known) and it works very well for text documents. You can get trained nets and python-Caffe scripts at [[Hradiš et al.: Convolutional Neural Networks for Direct Text Deblurring. BMVC 2015]](http://www.fit.vutbr.cz/~ihradis/CNN-Deblur/). This approach could work for other types of images, but it would not work for unrestricted photographs and diverse blurs. For general photos, I would guess It could work for small range of blurs.

Another possibility is to do inverse filtration (e.g. using Wiener filter) and process the output using a CNN. The advantage of this is that you can compute the inverse filter for new PSF very fast and the CNN stays the same. [Schuler et al.: A machine learning approach for non-blind image deconvolution. CVPR 2013]